# how do I insert a cookie into a urllib2 openerdirector object?

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

Is there a way to append a cookie into an already made and used openerdirector object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

# load cookies from file
saved_cookies = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('cookie_file_name')
saved_cookies.load()

opener = urllib2.build_opener() # your opener director

# do something...
opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(saved_cookies))
```

EDIT: According to [Python cookielib document](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.FileCookieJar.load), old cookies are kept unless overwritten by newly loaded ones.